# Prevent nested nav items from breaking on to the next line?

Tags: html, css

I have a basic horizontal nav menu, where a drop down list shows on hover. When the drop down links are single words everything works fine, but if the links are more than one word, ie "Lori Ipsum", the line breaks. I'm looking for the lines to keep their full width, so "Lori Ipsum" would be shown on the same line.

#### How can I prevent the line break?

Recreated in a code pen:  http://codepen.io/agconti/pen/zvjkm

html:

```
<nav role='navigation'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Aliquam tincidunt</li>
        <li>Vestibulum auctor</li>
      </ul>  
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

css:

```
html {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  transition: color 0.15s ease-out,  background-color 0.1s ease-in;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: pink;
}
ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
ul ul {
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
ul ul li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  minwidth: 100%;
}
ul ul li:hover {
  background: #ffa6b6;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Your codepen demo seems fine to me. I don't see any broken text.

Comment: @HashemQolami please take a look again. I reset the demo back to the original example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set li default width;

or use

```
li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware that `nowrap` can solve the issue, but I'd rather set the widths and styles appropriately so that I dont have to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am missing something, but you have a pretty good solution as is, and you could
fix the text wrap problem by specifying a width to the nest `ul` as follows:

```
ul ul {
  background-color: tan;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 300px;
}
```

I used 300px but you can pick a suitable value.

```css
html {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  transition: color 0.15s ease-out,  background-color 0.1s ease-in;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: pink;
}
ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
ul ul {
  background-color: tan;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 300px;
}
ul ul li {
  /*      white-space: nowrap;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  min-width: 100%;
}
ul ul li:hover {
  background: #ffa6b6;
  color: white;
}
ul ul li a {
  width: 200%;
}
```

```html
<nav role='navigation'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li>Aliquam tincidunt</li>
        <li>Vestibulum auctor</li>
      </ul>  
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>  
<section class="hero">
  <div class="mask"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm populating the li's text dynamically. So setting the lis to a fixed width would pose some problems if the text was ever larger.

Comment: There is no perfect solution for very long link texts.  Instead of setting a fixed width, set values for `min-width` and `max-width` and for the odd case with very long link texts, they can wrap onto a second line.

Answer (score 1):

```
li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```